# How to link Ceres to CGAL to use Smoothing functions?

Tags: cgal

I've built the Ceres package and its dependencies, now I'm trying to use the CGAL library to perform smoothing but I'm getting an error: "area-based smoothing requires ceres library".

How am I to incorporate the Ceres library? The CGAL smoothing example doesn't mention this and does not have any includes from the Ceres library.

I'm using CGAL in header-only mode without compilation, is it necessary to compile CGAL first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the cmake script of the examples using the smoothing, you can see the following line:

```
target_compile_definitions( mesh_smoothing_example PRIVATE CGAL_PMP_USE_CERES_SOLVER )
```

it is equivalent to add `#define CGAL_PMP_USE_CERES_SOLVER` in your code.

The rational is that if the lib is not found by cmake, the code will be disabled.

I agree that it is not correctly documented. An issue/PR has already been opened to improve the situation.

Comment: The new vcpkg for CGAL has since made installs of CGAL including Ceres integration very simple.

Comment: @James hi sorry to come back to this one year later. But what is the command for vcpkg to integrate `ceres` into `CGAL`? I'm having trouble finding this information